# Exception in exception handler C&C

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars

When I start the game(C&C Tiberium Wars) I get this error:
FATAL ERROR: Exception in exception handler

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: cnc3game.dat
  Application Version:  1.9.2801.21826
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    igdusc32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.18.14.4264
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55c1952d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0039d9a5
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 300b
  Additional Information 2: 300b6bae04fab042ce61851d7f2f171d
  Additional Information 3: 6876
  Additional Information 4: 6876f907424b380f357d6abfcd1730e8
```

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
CPU - i5 4690k
GPU - Intel HD 4600
RAM -  8GB X 1

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue with recent Intel HD graphics drivers. The only solution that has been found so far is to downgrade the drivers to a version from around/before June 2014.

[EDIT]

<s>This issue is apparently SOLVED in the latest drivers. Update your drivers.</s>

Issue reappeared some updates later. The June 2014 thing still seems to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have antivirus running? Avast is known to have issues with that file. For instance it crashes Office over it apperantly:

https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=170705.15

The file causing the corruption is the unified shader compiler add-on dll for Intel video chips.

I ran the game myself on a laptop, with an Intel HD device, using latest drivers, from my original disc, and i had no problems.

So i would suggest turning off AV and also to make sure you actually install the full HD driver package from Intel, not only the drivers that may have come with the computer (that may lack some components or be outdated)

I ran the game in compatibility mode for XP, so you can also try that.